# Mongo DB C# tutorial code not working

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am learning *Mongo DB C# driver* usage. I was following along the documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/insert/ and `InsertOneAsync` code example raised an exception, as follows:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The type initializer for 'TestMongo.Program' threw an exception.
```

This is my code file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace TestMongo
{
    class Program
    {
        protected static IMongoClient _client = new MongoClient();
        protected static IMongoDatabase _database = _client.GetDatabase("test");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InsertOneDocument();
        }

        static async Task InsertOneDocument()
        {
            var document = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "address" , new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "street", "2 Avenue" },
                        { "zipcode", "10075" },
                        { "building", "1480" },
                        { "coord", new BsonArray { 73.9557413, 40.7720266 } }
                    }
                },
                { "borough", "Manhattan" },
                { "cuisine", "Italian" },
                { "grades", new BsonArray
                    {
                        new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "date", new DateTime(2014, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                            { "grade", "A" },
                            { "score", 11 }
                        },
                        new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "date", new DateTime(2014, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                            { "grade", "B" },
                            { "score", 17 }
                        }
                    }
                },
                { "name", "Vella" },
                { "restaurant_id", "41704620" }
            };

            var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
            await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using **CSharpDriver-2.4.3** driver on **.Net 4.5** framework. Could anybody please give me a solution to the problem?

Comment: your code is working without any issue may be this a first exception only

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have any issue  but you don't await the execution

just change your main method and disable `CLR Exception` in your project to see if it was just a `first chance exception`

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InsertOneDocument().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
```

Comment: How to disable CLR Exception?

Comment: just  press CT+D,E and then  check  if Common language runtime exception was unchecked or not

Comment: `Ctrl+D,E` not working. Maybe shortcut is not mapped to the action.

Comment: CLR Exceptions **Thrown** unchecked, **User-unhandled** unchecked. Still getting the exception.

Comment: try to check if only enable only my code is checked  and desinstall and reinstall your mongo nuget package  may be this could help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143511/discussion-between-brahim-kamel-and-prakhar-mishra).

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because of this line:

```
protected static IMongoClient _client = new MongoClient();
```

Change it to this and it should work:

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
protected static IMongoClient _client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
```

Comment: `protected static string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";`

`protected static IMongoClient _client = new MongoClient(connectionString);`
Still, not working

Comment: no by default  moongoclient is on localhost if no argument was sent

Comment: Is your local MongoDB running?